# How to decode javascript error

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am downloading file by clicking on link from ExtJS grid column.

After download When I go back to my Application page I am getting one notification by

**The operation failed due to a system error. Please try again.**

In fiddler I am checking

I am getting this error with 200 CODE.

My Question is how to decode this.

> ErrorInfo=Invalid%20Element%20%22id%22%3A%20%22COSMIC%20Mutation%20Data%20v77%22%3Cbr%3ESource%20%3AExt.dom.Element%3Cbr%3EMethod%3Aconstructor%3Cbr%3E%27
>   & ErrSource =Java%20Script

Answer (score 0):

Your error states

```
ErrorInfo=Invalid Element "id": "COSMIC Mutation Data v77"<br>Source :Ext.dom.Element<br>Method:constructor<br>' & ErrSource =Java Script
```

You can try this tool to decode such urls 
https://www.url-encode-decode.com/

:)